# Custom PS1 not showing the current working directory

Tags: unix, profile, ps1

I have customized the primary prompt for bash shell but unfortunately it is not showing the current working directory as can be seen below.

```
[cifsamidala]w# pwd
/home/Vinod/SearchIdIssue
[cifsamidala]w#
```

Here is what I have customized my PS1:

```
HOST=`tput bold``hostname``tput sgr0`
PS1="[${HOST}]\w # "
```

Here is the Shell info for your reference.

```
[cifsamidala]w# echo $SHELL
/sbin/sh
[cifsamidala]w# echo $0
-sh
```

I also tried with 'pwd' as below but of no use.

```
PS1="[${HOST}]`pwd` # "
```

Kindly let me know if I am missing something here.

Thanks in avance.

Regards,

Vinod Yadav

Comment: Noticing /sbin/sh, maybe this is not bash, or a restricted shell. What's the output of $BASH_VERSION? Does the shopt command show some restriction being ON?

Comment: ThanQ for your comments. 
Unfortunately both these these are not showing any result. [cifsamidala]#echo $BASH_VERSION
sh: BASH_VERSION: Parameter not set.
[cifsamidala]#man shopt
No manual entry for shopt.
[cifsamidala]#
[cifsamidala]#shopt
sh: shopt:  not found.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell is not the bash shell and this is probably the reason why it won't work. Ask your sysadmin to give you an unrestricted shell.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please tell me how to figure out whether the shell is a restricted ?

Comment: This would depend on which shell this /sbin/sh actually is, which I don't know how to find out, sorry.