# Variable names in prompt instead of path

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, zsh, zshrc

How can I prevent my zsh prompt from showing the variable name a path is assigned to instead of the path itself?

```
foo="/some/path"
cd "$foo"
```

shows `$ ~foo/` in my prompt instead `$ /some/path/`

Comment: Are you using `zsh` or `bash`? You can't be using both at once. That aside, you're seeing [`Named Directories`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l20). Check if `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` is set (`setopt | grep AUTO_NAME_DIRS`) - to disable this functionality, turn it off.

Comment: `PS1` is the variable containing the format of your prompt. Check some questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911378/custom-ps1-not-showing-the-current-working-directory/10926517#10926517

Comment: @simont thanks. I use zsh. The option it's called "autonamedirs" on my machine and I unset it via unsetopt autonamedirs and it worked.

Comment: @fedorqui thank you. I know about PS1 but the behaviour as I described before is obviously connected to "Named Directories" as simont described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments:

you're seeing [Named Directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l20). Check if `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` is set (`setopt | grep AUTO_NAME_DIRS`) - to disable this functionality, turn it off.