# zsh prompt uses variables names (despite unsetting AUTO_NAME_DIRS)

Tags: terminal, zsh, zshrc

I have assigned a directory to a variable in my .zshrc file like so:

`export DOTFILES=$HOME/.dotfiles`

Now my zsh prompt reads `~DOTFILES` when I am in the `.dotfiles` directory. I did some research (in this thread: [Variable names in prompt instead of path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203555/variable-names-in-prompt-instead-of-path)) and found that zsh has an `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` option which does this very thing.

I tried `unsetopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS` but my zsh prompt still shows the variable name instead of the path. I ran the `unsetopt` command and found that `autonamedirs` is indeed in the list of unset options. I also ran `setopt` to make sure it wasn't in the list of set options, and it is not.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Think of it as a hook to create named directories that is triggered at variable setting.**

So if `auto_name_dirs` parameter is set and you set some value `% TMP=/tmp`, it will also create a named dir for `/tmp` using `TMP`. If you later unset the parameter, the *directory name* remains. If you create a number of variables `% USER=/usr` with `auto_name_dirs` unset, and after set the option, no directory naming will take place.

```
~ % zsh -f
dhcp-193-107% setopt autonamedirs
dhcp-193-107% TMP=/tmp
dhcp-193-107% export PS1="dir-prompt %~ : "
dir-prompt ~ : cd /tmp
dir-prompt ~TMP : unset autonamedirs
dir-prompt ~TMP : cd /
dir-prompt / : cd /tmp
dir-prompt ~TMP : # see the dir name still exists
dir-prompt ~TMP : USER=/usr     
dir-prompt ~TMP : cd /usr
dir-prompt /usr : # no dir name for /usr
dir-prompt /usr : setopt autonamedirs
dir-prompt /usr : cd /
dir-prompt / : cd /usr
dir-prompt /usr : # still no dir name for /usr
```

Comment: Thanks for the great illustration - it really helped me narrow down the the solution (detailed above).